# Apostille two times of the same document with a translation added

Tags: visas, italy

I don't know what is exactly meant by the these document requirements:

1- certified copy of the high school diploma with apostille;

2- translation of the high school diploma into Italian performed by an official translator (sworn at the Court) and equipped with apostille;

Now, am I required to do two apostilles, this is impossible, because Apostille is issued for a single unique document, either as original or legalized, not translation.

What is meant?

Answer (score 10):

**It's perfectly possible and common.**

Usually, the procedure goes as follows:

- Start with an official document that you need to use abroad.
- Get that document apostilled by the appropriate government authority in the country of issue (could be perhaps a Department of Education or Foreign Affairs or something else).
- Get the document including the apostille translated by a sworn translator. The translator will give you a translation including a "translator's statement" saying something like "I, a sworn translator, hereby certify that this translation is accurate.". *This statement is your new official document that you need apostilled.*
- Get the translation (actually, the statement) apostilled by the appropriate authority (perhaps the court that's registering the translator, plus a Department of Justice or whatever is appropriate).

The final result is then a combination of four documents stapled together:

- The original document
- Apostille of the document
- The translation including translator's statement
- Apostille of the translation (statement)

It's thus not unusual for the two apostilles to be issued by different authorities (depending on your country).

Comment: Right, exactly!