# Should I translate the document before or after attesting it?

Tags: paperwork, translations

For visa purposes, I need to attest some documents with Apostille and translate them.

I have never done this before and nothing is mentioned on the website I am referring to, so I am not sure if the correct procedure is to get the documents translated or attested first. Or does it not matter?

Comment: Apostille is for original documents, usually

Comment: @littleadv Yes, I also figured that it's the original document that needs to be certified, not the translation. But does it matter if I translate before or after that?

Comment: You might need to ask whoever asked for it if they need the apostille also translated

Comment: @littleadv I would like to know the general common practice. I checked multiple websites and I did not find any note regarding this, so I assume that it's common knowledge for people with some experience with this.

Comment: "Yes, I also figured that it's the original document that needs to be certified, not the translation": this is usually not the case.  The original document itself is generally a certificate.  It needs to be authenticated, not certified, because it is already certifying something.  The translation itself often (not always) needs to be certified by a qualified or registered translator.  Details vary significantly, so a generalized question and answer may not be readily applicable to the visa for which you are applying.  The translator's certificate may also require authentication.

Comment: @phoog I used the wrong verb, I meant "attested", as in "attested with Apostille". I am asking about the authentication, not about certifying the translation.

Comment: I've moved countries twice, each with a language different than the previous. So I have had several documents translated and apostilled. The order you do it in doesn't matter. Generally, the apostille shouldn't need translating.

Comment: *General common practice* is nice, but useless if the requestor you're dealing with isn't following it. Different countries have different standards, different requirements, and different tolerance to deviations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apostille two times of the same document with a translation added](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157748/apostille-two-times-of-the-same-document-with-a-translation-added)

Comment: @TooTea Good find, but it's not the same question. In that one, the poster was specifically required to translate the Apostille.

Comment: @hb20007 It's the other way around. Nobody usually wants you to translate an apostille (it has a standard multilingual format),but you are often required to have the translation apostilled as well (one apostille certifying the original,another apostille certifying the translation).

Comment: @TooTea Yes, you're right :) In any case, for him/her the requirement was clearly mentioned.

Comment: An apostille by country A simply means "yes,this is an official document of country A". When you need a sworn/official translation of an official document,that requires two apostilles certifying two different things (that the original was issued by an authority,and that the translation is authoritative as well).

Comment: @TooTea I have updated the Community Wiki answer here based on the new information from the other question which you shared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the  [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/185727/should-i-translate-the-document-before-or-after-attesting-it#comment476310_185727) by Ozzy which states that the order did not matter for him/her, as well as [another question here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157748/apostille-two-times-of-the-same-document-with-a-translation-added) where the poster was required to Apostille the translator’s statement (“I, a sworn translator, hereby certify that…”) as well, we can conclude that **the document needs to be Apostilled first**, with 2 possible scenarios:

If the translation of the Apostilled document is performed by a certified translator in the country which issued the document or any third-party country, then the translator’s statement will need to be Apostilled in that country as well.

If the translation of the Apostilled document is performed by a certified translator in the country which has requested the document, then the translator’s statement will not need to be Apostilled as the translator is certified and acknowledged in the country.

In both cases, the document certification takes place first.